# socket.io client hangs up

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Using socket.io the client hangs up (page keeps loading) on posting a form - stopping the node server the client runs fine again instantly.

Server

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  io.sockets.emit('messages', { 
    user: req.body.user,
    message: req.body.message
  });
});
```

Client

```
<script src="socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('messages', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('.entry').first().before(
        '<div class="entry well well-large">'
        + data.user
        + ' says: '
        + data.message
        + '</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You should always end an HTTP request, but you're not doing that in your `post` handler. If you don't, Express won't return an answer to your browser and your browser will keep waiting for one (until at some point it gets tired of waiting and generates a timeout).

Try this instead:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  io.sockets.emit('messages', { 
    user: req.body.user,
    message: req.body.message
  });
  // end the request by ending the response
  res.end();
});
```

(it's not enough to send a message with `socket.io`, because that's a separate protocol)

Comment: @zimt28 accept and upvote the answer if it has helped you :)